# Getting rid of the parenthesis with regular expression group matching

Tags: regex, splunk

I'm trying to analyze logs using splunk and I need to parse lines that look like this:

```
2012-06-20 20:35:13,980 INFO  [http-bio-8080-exec-72] (b50f3a81-f9e0-4ebf-b9e2-b007c8dd4cbf) interceptor.CustomLoggingOutInterceptor (AbstractLoggingInterceptor.java:149)     - Outbound Message
```

I've got this regex which matches:

```
(?i)^[^\]]*\]\s+(?P<FIELDNAME>[^ ]+)
```

this part :

```
2012-06-20 20:35:13,980 INFO  [http-bio-8080-exec-72] (b50f3a81-f9e0-4ebf-b9e2-b007c8dd4cbf)
```

Using groups I can extract the real information that I need and that is :

```
(b50f3a81-f9e0-4ebf-b9e2-b007c8dd4cbf)
```

Only problem is that I don't need parenthesis, I've tried with some negative lookahead/lookbehind google searches, don't really know regex that well.

So my final goal would be to capture `b50f3a81-f9e0-4ebf-b9e2-b007c8dd4cbf` . thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?i)^[^\]]*\]\s+\((?P<FIELDNAME>[^ ]+)\)`

That matches and drops the `()` in group 1.

[Play with the regex here](http://regexr.com?31aiu).